# scrollTo() in DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using the following code to scroll to a specific absolute position of the document.
Document scrolls with no animation.

```
window.scrollTo(0, 500);
```

I would like to know if is it possible to use DOJO to scroll to a specific absolute position similarly to window.scrollTo() but with an animation effect.

Could you please provide me a sample of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `smoothScroll` from `dojox/fx/scroll`

```js
function scrollToFirst() {
  require(['dojox/fx/scroll'], function(scroll) {
    scroll({
        node: document.querySelector('#foo :first-child'),
        win: window
    }).play();
  });
}

function scrollToLast() {
  require(['dojox/fx/scroll'], function(scroll) {
    scroll({
        node: document.querySelector('#foo :last-child'),
        win: window
    }).play();
  });
}

function scrollToPosition() {
  require(['dojox/fx/scroll'], function(scroll) {
    scroll({
        target: {y: 300, x: 0},
        win: window
    }).play();
  });
}

function scrollToTop() {
  require(['dojox/fx/scroll', 'dojo/dom-geometry'], function(scroll, domGeom) {
    var pos  = domGeom.position(window.document.body);
    if(pos.y > 0) { pos.y = 0 }
    scroll({
        target: {y: pos.y * 2, x: 0},
        win: window
    }).play();
  });
}

function scrollToRandom() {
  require(['dojox/fx/scroll', 'dojo/dom-geometry'], function(scroll, domGeom) {
    var pos  = domGeom.position(window.document.body);
    var randomPosition = Math.round(Math.random() * pos.h);

    document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = randomPosition;
    if(randomPosition === pos.y) { return; }
    if(randomPosition < pos.y) { 
      if(pos.y > 0) { pos.y = 0 }
      randomPosition = (pos.y * 2) + randomPosition 
    }
    if(randomPosition > pos.y) { randomPosition = pos.y + randomPosition }
    
    scroll({
        target: {y: randomPosition, x: 0},
        win: window
    }).play();
  });
}
```

```css
.buttons {
  position: fixed
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<div class="buttons">
    <button onclick="scrollToFirst();">Scroll to first</button>
    <button onclick="scrollToPosition();">Scroll to a position in middle</button>
  <button onclick="scrollToTop();">Scroll to position Top</button>
    <button onclick="scrollToLast();">Scroll to last</button>
  <button onclick="scrollToRandom();">Scroll to random</button>
  <span>random position:</span><span id="pos"></span>
</div>
<div id="foo">
  <p>content first</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content last</p>
  
</div>
```

**EDIT:** By reverse engineering `dojox/fx/scroll` I found a way to scroll properly at any position of `window`. See `scrollToRandom()` and `scrollToTop()`

Comment: I have tried with that I was not able to scroll the window. Are you able to provide a sample of code? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @GibboK I've set up a snippets. I scroll `body` tag which does the full window scroll

Comment: 2nd edit. It does not use `body` anymore. You can directly scroll using `window`

Comment: thanks very much for your snippet. But I need to "scroll to" with a numeric, let's imagine, scroll window to 500px value not passing a node. Is it possible? Thanks for now.

Comment: @GibboK yes it is possible using `target` properties. See the updated snippet

Comment: I have notice there is a problem, try this https://jsbin.com/tigudapivu/edit?html,output click button "Scroll to Position" after "Scroll Up", issue is the window does not scroll up, it seems that the coordinate are not absolute. Any idea on this issue?

Comment: @GibboK I've edited the answer. You need some calculation to get at the correct position

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
dojox.fx.smoothScroll
```

See this example:

[DOJO smooth scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/merg/AQfP7/)

**EDIT:**

For absolute position use:

```
var target = this.isHorizontal ? {x: left, y: 0} : { x:0, y:top};
        dojox.fx.smoothScroll({
            target: target,
            win: this.thumbScroller,
            duration:300,
            easing:dojo.fx.easing.easeOut,
            onEnd: dojo.hitch(this, "_checkLoad", img, index)
        }).play(10);
```

Comment: I was trying dojox.fx.smoothScroll but I was not able to scroll the window. Are you able to provide a sample of code? Thanks in advance for your help.